# How to get ipv4 ip address with jquery?

Tags: javascript, ipv4

where I connect to internet, I have an always changing `ip address` and when I try to get ip address, it does not give my `ipv4` address which I am using in my web services to call web service.
can you suggest me anything?
Thanks.

Comment: there is no right answer there and doesnot work for me.

Comment: The point being made in that question is that you can't do it with javascript without hitting a server-side service.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a backend server you can use something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
   alert("Your ip: " + data.ip);
});
```

reference: http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/juJYJ/light/